# Howto find all open bugs for a particular boost version > 1.67?

Tags: boost

We have to document bug information for the SOUPs/OTS our software is using. This is required by authority.

Up to boost 1.67 it was no problem to look for open bugs of a particular version we were using:
[boost trac](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/query?status=assigned&status=new&status=reopened&version=Boost%201.67.0&type=Bugs) showed exactly the information the auditor is looking for. This way one can evaluate a particular boost version whether it is safe for the intended use of our product.

But unfortunately starting with boost 1.68 this reporting functionality is no longer available! For us it is impossible to look at each of the dozens of repositories to look for issues. And even in that case one has no chance to easily see whether a bug was fixed and if so, in which version version it was fixed, etc. The whole holy status information you could easily request in prior versions using boost trac has been vanished!

Is there still a possibility to look for the bug status of a particular boost version > 1.67?

Comment: Trac is deprecated. All the issues are now forwarded to the appropriate library. For example, here are the multiprecision bugs: https://github.com/boostorg/multiprecision/issues

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that Trac is deprecated: that **is** the issue! Unfortunately it is deprecated! The new approach issues per library might be optional ok, but if this is the only way to get to know any open issues (and then, how do you get an overview about all unresolved issues of a particular version for a library?) this is unacceptable from a professional point of view. For students it might be ok but not when you have to develop high-quality software that uses boost as a third-party library!

Comment: This is not unacceptable; it works great. Much better than trac did.

Comment: It works better for adding new bugs and searching for a particular open issue of the latest version, indeed. But the reporting functionality of GitHub - or how it is used by boost - is very bad. This was the strength of Trac. You could easily search for all unresolved bugs of a particual version. I know that non-professional developers have trouble to understand that professional software development cannot always use the latest version, but this is due to authorities. E.g. the FDA requires proper bug reporting for a particular version (i.e. older version). Up to 1.67 this was no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found a workaround to search for bugs that were opened for a particualar release. It is not as comfortable as under boost Trac, and since not every repository labels its bugs as `bugs`, the output consists of much more results than boost Trac would have done. And sorting/ordering the output by severity is - of course - not possible, because github does not distinguish the severity of the issues.

Here is the search command for Boost 1.68 on [Github's global search page](https://github.com/search):

```
org:boostorg -closed:<2018-08-09 created:<2018-12-12
```

First you have to look on [boost News](https://www.boost.org/users/news/) when your version of interest was current. In this case for Boost 1.68 this was from 2018-08-09 (publishing date of Boost 1.68) until 2018-12-12 (publishing date of successor version Boost 1.69). Then you can search for open issues during that phase using the above-mentionend command.

Intuitively one would perform the following search:

```
org:boostorg -closed:<2018-08-09 created:<2018-12-12 label:bug
```

but of course due to the federal system of libraries ;-) this is not useful since not every library labels its bugs as `bugs`.

Herewith I have proved that Boost Trac had been much more intuitive and better for reporting bugs for a particular version of interest than the new hip github does ;-) q.e.d.